# JAVA jar in sonarqube community editon

Tags: sonarqube

Can I use sonarqube community editon to analyze JAVA jar files as they are?

Is it to analyze only JAVA class files and source files?

No mention of it was found on the official page.

I tried it myself and it seems that jar files are ignored.

Please let me know as soon as possible.

Comment: Why would you want to put compiled objects through a static code analyser?